# i am hitting a twitter api url to get json data but not getting data which i wanted,how to fix it?

Tags: java, json, twitter

```
//my code looks like this.

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;  
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

        public class TwitterFeeds {        
                static String AccessToken = "xxxx";
                static String AccessSecret = "xxxx";
                static String ConsumerKey = "xxxx";
                static String ConsumerSecret = "xxxx";
        //getting json data from twitter api
                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
                    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(AccessToken, AccessSecret);

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mehral_mohit&count=2"); 

                    consumer.sign(request);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    System.out.println(obj.toString());
                }
        }
```

Response i am getting is like this

```
    {"statusLine":{"reasonPhrase":"OK","protocolVersion":{"protocol":"HTTP","major":1,"minor":1},"statusCode":200},"allHeaders":[{"valuePos":14,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"no-cache","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"no-store","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"must-revalidate","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"pre-check","value":"0","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"post-check","value":"0","parameters":[]}],"name":"cache-control","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0"},{"valuePos":20,"elements":[{"parameterCount":1,"name":"attachment","parameters":[{"name":"filename","value":"json.json"}]}],"name":"content-disposition","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"attachment; filename=json.json"},{"valuePos":15,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"7037","parameters":[]}],"name":"content-length","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"7037"},{"valuePos":13,"elements":[{"parameterCount":1,"name":"application/json","parameters":[{"name":"charset","value":"utf-8"}]}],"name":"content-type","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},{"valuePos":5,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"Wed","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"27 Apr 2016 17:27:40 GMT","parameters":[]}],"name":"date","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"Wed, 27 Apr 2016 17:27:40 GMT"},{"valuePos":8,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"Tue","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT","parameters":[]}],"name":"expires","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT"},{"valuePos":14,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"Wed","parameters":[]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"27 Apr 2016 17:27:40 GMT","parameters":[]}],"name":"last-modified","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"Wed, 27 Apr 2016 17:27:40 GMT"},{"valuePos":7,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"no-cache","parameters":[]}],"name":"pragma","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"no-cache"},{"valuePos":7,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"tsa_a","parameters":[]}],"name":"server","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"tsa_a"},{"valuePos":11,"elements":[{"parameterCount":1,"name":"lang","value":"en","parameters":[{"name":"Path","value":"/"}]}],"name":"set-cookie","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"lang=en; Path=/"},{"valuePos":11,"elements":[{"parameterCount":3,"name":"guest_id","value":"v1%3A146177806078426763","parameters":[{"name":"Domain","value":".twitter.com"},{"name":"Path","value":"/"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Fri"}]},{"parameterCount":0,"name":"27-Apr-2018 17:27:40 UTC","parameters":[]}],"name":"set-cookie","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"guest_id=v1%3A146177806078426763; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 27-Apr-2018 17:27:40 UTC"},{"valuePos":7,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"200 OK","parameters":[]}],"name":"status","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"200 OK"},{"valuePos":26,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"max-age","value":"631138519","parameters":[]}],"name":"strict-transport-security","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"max-age=631138519"},{"valuePos":15,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"read-write","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-access-level","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"read-write"},{"valuePos":18,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"3454ef82d8d78c83570609a400be310e","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-connection-hash","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"3454ef82d8d78c83570609a400be310e"},{"valuePos":23,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"nosniff","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-content-type-options","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"nosniff"},{"valuePos":16,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"SAMEORIGIN","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-frame-options","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"SAMEORIGIN"},{"valuePos":19,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"180","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-rate-limit-limit","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"180"},{"valuePos":23,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"179","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-rate-limit-remaining","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"179"},{"valuePos":19,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"1461778960","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-rate-limit-reset","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"1461778960"},{"valuePos":16,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"48","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-response-time","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"48"},{"valuePos":14,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"d4ec12da2dc12a43","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-transaction","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"d4ec12da2dc12a43"},{"valuePos":24,"elements":[{"parameterCount":0,"name":"BouncerCompliant","parameters":[]}],"name":"x-twitter-response-tags","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"BouncerCompliant"},{"valuePos":17,"elements":[{"parameterCount":1,"name":"1","parameters":[{"name":"mode","value":"block"}]}],"name":"x-xss-protection","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"1; mode=block"}],"protocolVersion":{"protocol":"HTTP","major":1,"minor":1},"locale":"en_US","params":{"clientParams":{},"requestParams":{}},"entity":{"streaming":true,"repeatable":false,"chunked":false,"contentLength":7037,"contentType":{"valuePos":13,"elements":[{"parameterCount":1,"name":"application/json","parameters":[{"name":"charset","value":"utf-8"}]}],"name":"content-type","buffer":{"empty":false,"full":false},"value":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"content":{}}}
```

Data which i am looking for is tweets by user ,but data i am getting is response statuses,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually reading the response of the server, but rather making your JSON library serialize the state of the connection. Reading the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) of the library you're using helps you avoid such issues by knowing what the purpose and capabilities of each class are.

You need to use the following code to read the actual server response, and ultimately get a string to be parsed by your JSON library:

```
byte[] respData = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(new String(respData));
```

Comment: i am getting nothing in json object now getting {} ,when i do obj.toString();.

Comment: @MohitMehral Fixed a bug in my answer. Please try again with new version (that actually converts byte array to a string for parsing)

Comment: but the length of my json object is 0 @hexafraction

Comment: @MohitMehral What is the content of `new String(respData)`?

Comment: i converted the bytearray into string but when i am storing that string in jsonObject ,and trying to print that jsonObject i am getting error as Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:188)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:314)

Comment: OK, so what does the string contain, exactly?

Comment: I used JSONArray instead of jsonobject, because the response i was getting was having [ ] not { } so jsonarray  worked